# Open Books in text format for easy parsing?

Tags: books

Are there any open data "book" collections, like Shakespeare, and other authors, in text format for easy parsing? Ideally in English, but any other language is welcome too!

Comment: Free ebooks of classical literature: https://www.gutenberg.org/  (not only classics, but all kinds of stuff that has entered public domain according to US law)